# How to compare text file and csv file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a txt file call **EmployeeID.txt** that look something like this

```
Number      ID
32324       KLEON
23424       MKEOK
```

and I have a CSV file called **FullInventory.csv** that look something like this

```
Name     URL        UPN               Status
John    http://     KLEON@COM.COM     Yes
```

I'm trying to compare the two files and out put 2 different file called **matchFound.cs**v and **notFound.txt** file.

If an **ID** from EmployeeID.txt is found in FullInventory.csv then output **matchFound.csv** with the all the column from FullInventory.csv

If an **ID** from EmployeeID.txt is NOT found in FullInventory.csv then output **NotFound.txt** with a data from EmployeeId.txt

```
$ImportTXT = Import-CSV -path $Global:EmployeeID -Delimiter "`t"
$ImportFullInv = Import-CSV -Path $Global:FullInventory 


ForEach ($TxtLine in $ImportTXT) {
  $TxtID = $TxtLine.ID

  if ($null -eq $txtID -or $txtID -eq '') {
    Write-Host "ID is empty"
  }
  else {
    $array = @();

    ForEach ($CSVLine in $ImportFullInv) {
      $CSVUPN = $CSVLine.UPN
      $UPNSPLIT = $CSVUPN -split "@"
      $array += $UPNSPLIT[0]
    }

    if ($array -contains $TxtID) {
    // Something is not right here.
   
      $CSVLine |  Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\matchFound.csv" -append
    

  
    }
    else {
      $TxtLine | Out-File -FilePath  "C:\Users\Desktop\notFound.txt" -append

    }
  }
}
```

The problem I have right now is matchFound.csv file is not outputting the correct Data. I think it outputting the last data columns from the csv file instead of the one that it matched.
Any help or suggestion would be really apprecaited.

Comment: As a general aside: [Try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it might become pretty expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `Group-Object -AsHashtable` to allow fast lookups, the hash Keys would be the `Name` extracted from the `UPN` column. In addition to export this to two different files, you use a [steppable pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/) instead of using `-Append`.

```bash
$map = Import-Csv $FullInventory -Delimiter "`t" |
    Group-Object { [mailaddress]::new($_.UPN).User } -AsHashTable -AsString

$pipeMatch = { Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Desktop\matchFound.csv' -NoTypeInformation }.GetSteppablePipeline()
$pipeMatch.Begin($true)

Import-Csv $EmployeeID -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach-Object {
    # if this ID exists in the full inventory
    if($map.ContainsKey($_.ID)) {
        # export all rows from inventory matching this ID
        $map[$_.ID] | ForEach-Object { $pipeMatch.Process($_) }
        # and go to the next ID
        return
    }

    # else, export this line to the not found csv
    $_
} | Export-Csv "C:\Users\Desktop\notFound.csv" -NoTypeInformation

$pipeMatch.End()
```

Comment: Once again thank you so much Santiago for the help. Really appreciated it.

Comment: @aasenomad my pleasure, glad it was helpful :)

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon I have a lot data in both file, over 124,654 users and it taking a very long time finish so I'm just wondering if you know if there is a faster process?.

Comment: @aasenomad perhaps changing the `ForEach-Object` for a `foreach` loop would make this go faster but you would be sacrificing memory for performance. If you have enough memory then it would be fine. If you can ask a new question that would be great